# Declaring A variable inside dynamic ssql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following string and would like to replace >30 at the end of the string with @value so I can pass it through a stored procedure. How do I declare @value. My orginal code had >35' in place of vaule and worked fine. Thanks in advance.

```
 Declare @value  int
 set  @value=30

 exec (' insert into results_stats select'''+
@tab_name+''','''+@col_name+''',max(len('+@col_name+')),'+@col_name+','''+@dat 
a_type+'''  from LIVE.'+@tab_name+' Group By '+@col_name+' Having 
max(len('+@col_name+'))'''+@value+'')
```

Comment: That code is **dangerously** open to injection. You *need* to parametrise your statements, and safely inject the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`sp_executesql()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Read through the documentation in the link; it covers how to do this in detail.

The other thing to be aware of is you may need to include the `>` operator from your `>35` as part of the string literal.